# Python - clicking a javascript button

Tags: javascript, python, html, post

I have a button on a page that needs to be clicked for me to move on to the next page in a sequence, and I was wondering how this is possible with Python. The button seems to be the mix of an HTTP POST request and Javascript, here is the code for the button:

```
<FORM name="ff" action="nq2.phtml" method="post">
  <INPUT type="hidden" name="target" value="-1">
  <INPUT type="hidden" name="fact" value="">
  <INPUT type="hidden" name="parm" value="">
  <INPUT type="hidden" name="use_id" value="-1">
  <INPUT type="hidden" name="nxactor" value="1">
  <TD align="center" valign="top">
  <DIV class="pr">
  <A href="javascript:;" onClick="settarget(5); setch(ch5); return false;">
```

I honestly have no idea how to approach something like this and was wondering if anyone had some insight about how I would go about doing it.

Comment: What does settarget() function do? Anyway you can't do it with Python but you have to do it with javascript (with a setTimeout() if you need delay).

Comment: @FabioBuda Apparently you can! ;)

Comment: How did you get the code for this button? Wireshark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To simulate the submission of a form, you can send the same POST request that your browser will send to the site once the submit button is clicked. One way to do this is use `urllib.urlencode` to encode the form data from a dictionary and `urllib2.urlopen` to send the request:

```
import urllib, urllib2
form_data = urllib.urlencode({'target': <value>, 'fact': <value>, ...})
urllib2.urlopen("np2.phtml", form_data)
```

Comment: Hey, I'm dealing with a similar problem. The issue is that when I click the button it generates a hash which is sent to the website (so there is no way to know the POST request beforehand). what should one do in such a situation?

Comment: @Fozoro You might be dealing with a single page application. In that case, I'd try to reproduce the scenario you're interested in with something like [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) or [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/).

Comment: Great, thank you very much for your reply, I never heard of cypress before (will take a look into it). Nonetheless are you aware if this is even possible using the requests module (without selenium). Many thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: @Fozoro I'm afraid that sometimes you need to execute javascript code to get what you need and it looks like you're in that case.